# Are there generic templates for ggplot2 to help simplify the code?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am new to `ggplot2` and I am frustrated. It seems like you need a lot of code to generate a relatively simple plot like the one I illustrate below. Thirty lines of code, per my `ggplot` code shown at the bottom of this post. Are there simple, generic templates for creating plots sort of similar to what I illustrate below? Is there a package available for managing (simplifying) the `ggplot2` package? Are there simpler plot packages to deal with than `ggplot` for the non-discriminating user, but still more customizable than base R plot? Just like with desserts where the calories have to be justified by the quality of flavor, the below plot code complexity doesn't justify the output.

[image]

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(survival)

lung1 <- lung %>% 
  mutate(time1 = ifelse(time >= 500, 500, time)) %>% 
  mutate(status1 = ifelse(status == 2 & time >= 500, 1, status))

weibCurve <- function(time, survregCoefs) {exp(-(time/exp(survregCoefs[1]))^exp(-survregCoefs[2]))}

fit1 <- survreg(Surv(time1, status1) ~ 1, data = lung1)

lung1.survfit <- survfit(Surv(time1, status1) ~ 1, data = lung1)
lung1.df <- data.frame(time = lung1.survfit$time, 
                       survival = lung1.survfit$surv, 
                       upper_95 = lung1.survfit$upper, 
                       lower_95 = lung1.survfit$lower)

# generate simulation paths
n_simulations <- 50
simPaths <- data.frame(x = seq(from = 500, to = 1000, by = 5))
simPathList <- lapply(1:n_simulations, function(i) {
  newCoef <- MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1, fit1$icoef, vcov(fit1))
  y <- weibCurve(simPaths$x, newCoef)
  simPaths[[paste0("y", i)]] <- y
  simPaths
})

simPaths_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "x", all = TRUE), simPathList)
simPaths_df_long <- pivot_longer(simPaths_df, -x, names_to = "sim", values_to = "survival")

fit_km <- summary(survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung))
plot_km <- data.frame(x = fit_km$time, y = fit_km$surv)

lung1.df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = survival)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, group = sim, color = "Simulations"), data=simPaths_df_long) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95, fill = "Confidence Interval"), 
              alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Confidence Interval" = "grey50"), name = NULL) +
  geom_line(aes(y = survival, color = "K-M actual data to period 500"), linewidth = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1500)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0, 0.05)) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Survival probability", color = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  stat_function(fun = weibCurve, args = list(survregCoefs = fit1$icoef), 
                aes(color = "Weibull distribution fit"), size = 1, n = 1000) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(
      "K-M actual data to period 500"="blue", 
      "K-M actual data after period 500"="black", 
      "Weibull distribution fit"="red", 
      "Simulations"="lightblue",
      "Confidence Interval"="grey50")
  ) +
  labs(color = NULL) +
  geom_step(data = plot_km %>% filter(x > 500), 
            aes(x = x, y = y, color = "K-M actual data after period 500"), 
            size = 1, alpha = 0.7) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.95, 0.95), 
        legend.justification = c(1, 1),
        legend.title.align = 0.5, 
        legend.box.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"), 
        legend.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

Comment: Take a look at [awesome-ggplot2](https://github.com/erikgahner/awesome-ggplot2), in particular `ggsurvfit` and `survminer` in your case

Comment: There are tons of ggplot wrappers that aim to make it easier to use ggplot. The problem with all of them is what you gain in ease-of-use you lose in your ability to customize the plot. What you are plotting is not simple here. You have four different (sets of) lines from four different data sources, a confidence interval and lots of specific theming choices. You could get the plotting code down to five or six lines by getting your data into a single data frame and using a nice default theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of ggplot wrappers that aim to make it easier to generate a plot from a given data set. The problem with all of them is what you gain in ease-of-use you lose in your ability to customize the plot.

What you are plotting is *not* simple here. You have a single KM series that you want to display with two colours before and after an arbitrary cutoff, a confidence band with an arbitrary cutoff, a cluster of simulations you want to plot as lines, and a theoretical distribution to draw over the whole thing. You use four different data sources to achieve this. It's pretty clear that there will not be a simple wrapper out there that covers your specific use case.

It is worth pointing out that a few of your code lines are redundant, and that many of the lines of code are devoted to labelling / renaming things in the data. This has to be done *somewhere* if you want your plot labelled correctly.

You are also using several lines to specify theme elements. There are some great pre-existing themes out there, and you might save a lot of code (and tweaking) by choosing one you like and sticking with it.

If you cobble your data together into a single data frame, you can get a near-identical plot using this considerably shorter code:

```r
ggplot(plot_df, aes(time, survival, color = col, group = sim)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_95, ymax = upper_95, 
                  fill = "Confidence Interval"), color = NA, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(col == 'Simulations')) +
  geom_step(data = . %>% filter(type == 'step')) +
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(col == 'Weibull distribution fit')) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = 'gray50') +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c('black', 'blue', 'lightblue', 'red')) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.7, 0.8))
```

[image]

It does require getting the data into an appropriate format for plotting first, but if you are more comfortable with data wrangling than plotting, this might be the way to go. The following code was used to create `plot_df` for the above example:

```r
plot_df <- plot_km %>% 
  filter(x > 500) %>%
  rename(time = x, survival = y) %>%
  mutate(upper_95 = NA, lower_95 = NA, 
         col = 'K-M actual data after period 500') %>%
  bind_rows(lung1.df %>% mutate(col = 'K-M actual data to period 500')) %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(type = 'step') %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(time = 1:1500, survival = weibCurve(1:1500, fit1$icoef),
                       upper_95 = NA, lower_95 = NA,
                       col = "Weibull distribution fit",
                       type = 'line')) %>%
  mutate(sim = col) %>%
  bind_rows(simPaths_df_long %>% rename(time = x) %>% 
              mutate(upper_95 = NA, lower_95 = NA, col = 'Simulations', 
                     type = 'line') %>%
              dplyr::select(time, survival, upper_95, lower_95, col, type, sim))
```

Overall, this doesn't really make things any simpler, but it shows that it is not actually the plot code that is verbose or complex; rather, it is preparing and labelling the data that is verbose and complex. Doing it all inside ggplot can give the impression that the plotting code is arduous, when it is actually *organising the data* that is arduous.

Comment: The code is much easier to follow when organised this way too.